# How do I store Excel data into Firebase?

Tags: excel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Excel sheet of all my data (thousands and thousands of rows).  How do I get that "loaded" into Firebase to be used?

I've created a Firebase project and tried to look at some tutorials for the realtime database but that's not quite what I want.  I don't want real-time data quite yet.  I just want data that I have to be loaded in first.  How do I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I figured this out on my own.

First, take the Excel spreadsheet and clean it up in such a way that the first row contains the headers and everything else is the actual data.  Remember that Firebase keys (which correspond to column headers) must be UTF-8 encoded which means that it cannot contain . $ # [ ] / or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127.

Then, save it as a CSV file.  For example, on Excel 2013 it would be: File > Export > Change File Type > CSV.

Then, visit various resources online that can do CSV to JSON conversion.  The one I used was: http://codebeautify.org/csv-to-xml-json

Finally, take that .json file and load it into the Firebase database. Voila!

Comment: I can't converte csv to JSON with the web site you propose. the problem is that the first column is the firebase Node Key and it's treated same as the other columns (wich are child node)

Comment: You can use this [link](http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json) to convert csv to json.@MosesAprico

Comment: "take that .json file and load it into the Firebase database" how?

Comment: @ThierryC I'm facing the same obstacle as well, do you solve this issue?

Comment: @HatemHusam you can try this online site for example : https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm . To convert in hierarchical mode click on "CSV to Keyed JSON" (choose before which key is your node key, the 1 by default)

Answer (score 21):

STEPS TO UPLOAD COUNTRY LIST IN FIREBASE:

1. download country list with country code, currency code and currency name what you require:
2. convert it into csv.
3. convert csv into json from (https://codebeautify.org/csv-to-xml-json#).
4. validate json from https://jsonlint.com/
5. save in a file say test.json.
6. open firebase with login.
7. select database.
8. click on (...) in verticle,  beside + - sign,
9. click on import.
10. browse and select test.json file
11. import
12. now it is great!!!!!!! cheers!

Comment: For others landing here in 2018 forward as me: the "(...) beside + - " will only appear if you chose a 'Realtime Database' and not 'Cloud Firestone'. Don't know how to do the steps above on the later.

Comment: @mrbTT is correct. At the time of this comment Cloud Firestore is in BETA and  does not allow the import or export of JSON objects.

Comment: How about we upload excel sheet on cloud storage , use convert-excel-to-json / xlsx2json etc. npm library to read data and put data into database